# How can I dump a MySQL database from mysql c library

Tags: c++, c, mysql

I want to archive my database of mysql. Kindly give me some guide lines how I can make it possible, I am using mysql c library for insertion and selection etc. I dont know how to use dump command.

Comment: Look at the MySQL manual for the SQL syntax of `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SHOW TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) and [DESCRIBE tbl_name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) queries to obtain structure of database and tables. Then, use SELECT to fetch data and proceed it to your output according to the structure.